Can I load the metrics API into my envtest tests?
I'm building a custom Go/Kubebuilder operator that includes a vertical autoscaling component.  My reconciler can query the Metrics API to get basic per-Pod memory and CPU metrics, compare these to thresholds, and change the resource specification for the Pods it manages.
This code works great in a real cluster.  I can use the k8s.io/metrics Go API to access it, and so long as I register it with a Scheme, the controller-runtime fake client works with it.  Both the Kubebuilder documentation and the fake-client documentation strongly recommend using envtest in preference to the fake client, though, and here's where I'm having trouble.
The metrics API documentation notes:

The Metrics API is defined in the k8s.io/metrics repository. You must enable the API aggregation layer and register an APIService for the metrics.k8s.io API.

How can I do this in my envtest setup?  Right now I have basically the boilerplate provided by kubebuilder
testEnv = &envtest.Environment{
    CRDDirectoryPaths:     []string{filepath.Join("..", "config", "crd", "bases")},
    ErrorIfCRDPathMissing: true,
}
cfg, err := testEnv.Start()

Of note, the metrics API is not a custom resource, and there is no CustomResourceDefinition for it.  The boilerplate includes an option to install the Prometheus operator but this doesn't seem to enable the metrics API.
